# Django Rest Framework, add object to request.data and then call serializer is_valid()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm wondering which is the best way to solve this, I have a nested serializer like this:

serializers.py:

```
class PaymentMethodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    data = serializers.JSONField()
    payment_type = PaymentTypeSerializer(required=False)
```

Then, the view looks something like this:

```
class PaymentMethodView(APIView):
    def put(self, request, id):

        try:
            payment_method = PaymentMethod.objects.get(id=id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Response("No PaymentMethod with that id", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        payment_method_serialized = PaymentMethodSerializer(instance=payment_method, data=request.data)
        payment_type = request.data.get("payment_type", None)

        if payment_type:
            try:
                payment_method_type = PaymentType.objects.get(id=payment_type)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                payment_method_type = None
        else:
            payment_method_type = None

    # Now, call is_valid()
        if payment_method_serialized.is_valid():
            payment_method_serialized.save(payment_type=payment_method_type)
            return Response(payment_method_serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

`is_valid()` returns False and this error:

```
{"payment_type":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."]}}
```

I understand it, I'm giving the serializer a `pk`. However I don't want to create a new serializer with a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` instead of the nested relationship just for this. How can I get the `PaymentType` that corresponds to that `pk` and then add that object to the `request.data` dictionary so that `is_valid` doesn't fail? is it the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose `payment_type` is `ForeignKey` field in a `PaymentMethod` model, with `null=True` because of `required=False`.
If you provide only a `pk` so you don't need serializer for it field, you can just write in `fields`, like all other fields.

```
class PaymentMethodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    data = serializers.JSONField()

    class Meta:
        model = PaymentMethod
        fields = ('data', 'payment_type')
```

It will accept `pk` or `None`. If you want to provide special representation for your `PaymentType` model, you can override a `to_representation()` method.

```
class PaymentMethodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(PaymentMethodSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['payment_type'] = PaymentTypeSerializer(instance.payment_type).data
        return representation
```

Now it will use PaymentTypeSerializer for representation of related `PaymentType` model.
You can move you `payment_type` validation in a `serializer` though. Override `to_internal_value`, check provided `PaymentType` pk and throw an exception if it wrong and then catch that exception in a view.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Even though I didn't follow this solution. I did find the last paragraph very helpful: "You can move you payment_type validation in a serializer though. Override to_internal_value, check provided PaymentType pk and throw an exception if it wrong and then catch that exception in a view." That is why this I accepted this answer.