# How to post data to Django rest API

Tags: python, django, rest, post

I have a Django model that looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "ticker": "AAPL",
        "balance_sheet": [],
        "income_statement": [],
        "cash_flows": []
    },
    {
        "ticker": "MSFT",
        "balance_sheet": [],
        "income_statement": [],
        "cash_flows": []
    }
]
```

I want to add in the income_statement data using the `requests.post` function but cannot figure out how the data should be structured.  I get a 400 BAD REQUEST response from the server.

What is the problem ?

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/stocks/', data={ 'ticker': 'MSFT',
                                                        'income_statement': [{
                                                             'annualNetIncomeContinuousOperations': 45687000000,
                                                             'annualTaxEffectOfUnusualItems': 0,
                                                             'annualNetIncomeFromContinuingOperationNetMinorityInterest': 45687000000,
                                                             'annualTotalOperatingIncomeAsReported': 60024000000,
                                                              ... , 
                                                              ... , 
                                                              ...
                                         }]
                                      }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason this doesn't work is because of a concept called nested serialization.  more info can be found at the following link [Django REST Framework POST nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312558/django-rest-framework-post-nested-objects)