# Django rest framework foreign key display details from table 1 to table 2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 model, MyUser, Family.

What i want to do is display users details in Family table based on the MyUser table. It is like adding friends or family in other social media and display them

In my current Family table, there are these 3 field. userId , familyId and relationship:

userId(foreign key from MyUser table) = current user

familyId(foreign key from MyUser table) = current user's family member

relationship = who is the family member to the current user (eg: mother, father)

But i want to display **only some of** userId and familyId details from MyUser so the result will be like this:

**expected result**

```
userId = { id = 1, username = tom, image = "/media/images1/asdasdsda000.PNG"}
familyId = { id = 2, username = steve, image = "/media/images1/asdasdsda111.PNG"}
relationship = father
```

**current result**

```
userId = 1
familyId = 2
relationship = father
```

How do i do it ? I thought about nested serializer but i only want to display user details but not edit it from there.

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images1')
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6)

class Family(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    familyId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['userId', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'image']
        read_only_fields = ('userId',)
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'userId', 'familyId', 'relationship')
```

**views.py**

```
class MyUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer

class MyUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Family.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FamilySerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NestedSerializer

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['userId', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'image']
        read_only_fields = ('userId',)
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = MyUserSerializer()
    family = MyUserSerializer()    
    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'family', 'relationship')
```

Comment: How do i customise the output and the post field ? As i only want to enterjust userId and familyId.

Comment: I am not sure but probably this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308406/django-rest-framework-add-object-to-request-data-and-then-call-serializer-is-va